# Negative Binomial Distribution R

Tags: r, probability, self-study, negative-binomial-distribution

This question was given in class and I was wondering how to do this in R:

*"Sixty percent of a large lot of old spark plugs are still usable, and they can be individually tested to determine this. Let Y be the number plugs to be tested in order to find 5 usable items."*

```
Find the probability P[Y<=10]
```

I wish to apply the Negative Binomial distribution. I know the answer to be 0.834. This is the R code that I was working on. This returns the wrong answer.

```
sum(dnbinom(x=0:10,size=10,prob=0.6))
[1] 0.8724788
```

This set of parameters seem to return the correct answer, but I don't know why it is correct.

```
sum(dnbinom(x=0:5,size=5,prob=0.6))
[1] 0.8337614
```

Comment: I find the quoted question confusing. Did you mean to type "*in order to* ***find*** *5 useable items*"?

Comment: What do you think `dnbinom(x=0:10,size=10,prob=0.6)` does -- and how does "5 useable items" come into that calculation? Why sum results from `dnbinom` rather than simply calling `pnbinom`?

Comment: Fixed the question, yes I meant to type "in order to find 5 useable items"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum(dnbinom(x=0:10,size=10,prob=0.6))` is unlikely to be correct as it does not use the $5$ in the question.

The help page says *"This represents the number of failures which occur in a sequence of Bernoulli trials before a target number of successes is reached"* and *"`size` target for number of successful trials"*,
so to get $5$ successes in up to to $10$ trials, you can afford $0$ through to $5$ failures.  So either of these will work (the second uses the cumulative distribution function):

```
sum(dnbinom(x=0:(10-5), size=5, prob=0.6))
pnbinom(x=10-5, size=5, prob=0.6)
```

You could reformulate the question using a binomial distribution: you want at least $5$ successes in $10$ attempts.  So any of these work too:

```
sum(dbinom(x=5:10, size=10, prob=0.6))
1 - pbinom(q=5-1, size=10, prob=0.6)
pbinom(q=5-1, size=10, prob=0.6, lower.tail=FALSE)
```