# What is the probability that exactly k tosses are required to get exactly 2 Heads

Tags: probability

I have the following homework problem: *What is the probability of that exactly k tosses are required to get exactly 2 Heads*

I wanted to validate that my approach to solving this is correct and if my answer is on the right track:

$$A = P(\text{only 1 H in first $k-1$ tosses}) \cdot P(\text{H in last toss})$$

$$A=P(\text{only 1 H in first $k-1$ tosses}) \cdot .5$$

Is this the correct approach? Also below is my answer; is this correct or am I way off?

$$
\frac{k-1}{2 ^{k-1}} \cdot .5
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ethan. Your instincts are spot on.  1) When you ask what is obviously a homework question, you should report how far you got. 2) Your approach is correct. 1 heads in $k-1$ tosses and a heads on the last toss. So two things: 1) please use the self-study tag when you are asking about a homework problem, and 2) please try to master $\LaTeX$, including the binomial coefficient, so others will be able to see more easily how you are doing your counting.    $\LaTeX$ *will take you places!*

Comment: On the mathematics front (specifically MathJax's subset of LaTeX), see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @PeterLeopold Thank you so much for all of the feedback. I will make sure to do both things you recommend. Kind Regards, Ethan

Comment: Notice that your answer (+1), which simplifies to $(1-k)(1/2)^k,$ matches the result in my Answer. So your statement of the problem matches the formulation of the negative binomial distribution I chose in my Answer.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is related to the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations), which has several versions (see the link under 'alternative formulations'). You should compare the various formulations with your text
to avoid confusion. For this Answer I use a formulation used in many
elementary texts.

In a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with Success probability $p,$ let $X$ count the the number of *trials* $x = r, r+1, \dots$ until $r$ Successes have been observed.

Before the last trial (a Success), there must have been $x-1$ trials with $r - 1$ Successes. There are ${x-1 \choose r-1}$ possible
arrangements of Successes and Failures each with probability $p^{r-1}(1-p)^{x-r}.$ The final trial must be a Success with probability $p$. Thus
$$P(X = x) = {x-1 \choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{x-r},$$
for $x = r, r+1, \dots .$

In your problem, $r = 2, p = \frac 12,$ so that 
$$P(X = x) = (x-1)\left(\frac 12\right)^2\left(\frac 12\right)^{x-2}
= (x-1)\left(\frac 12\right)^x.$$

According to this formulation of a negative binomial random variable $X,$
we have $E(X) = \frac rp = \frac {2}{1/2} = 4$ and 
$Var(X) = \frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}= 4,$ which can be found using moment generating functions (or some other argument using differentiation).

For your problem, we can use R to sum the first 100 terms of (three)
infinite series to get good approximations:

```
x = 2:102; pdf = (x-1)*(.5)^x
sum(pdf)
[1] 1                  # 100 terms include almost probability 1
mu = sum(x*pdf); mu
[1] 4                  # for E(X), aprx with 100 terms very close
sum(x^2*pdf) - mu^2
[1] 4                  # also for Var(X)
```

*Note:* The formulation of the [negative binomial in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125477/negative-binomial-distribution-r) with functions `dnbinom`, and so on (not used above), counts the number of *Failures* before the $r$th Success. Examples:

```
mean(rnbinom(10^6, 2, .5) + 2)  # mean of sample of size 1 million
[1] 4.001245
x = 2:12; pdf = (x-1)*(.5)^x;  pdf
 [1] 0.250000000 0.250000000 0.187500000 0.125000000 0.078125000 0.046875000
 [7] 0.027343750 0.015625000 0.008789062 0.004882812 0.002685547
dnbinom(0:10, 2, .5)
 [1] 0.250000000 0.250000000 0.187500000 0.125000000 0.078125000 0.046875000
 [7] 0.027343750 0.015625000 0.008789062 0.004882813 0.002685547
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct to me. I'd only be more consistent in the notation, either use decimals $.5$ or fractions $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Upvoting in spite of bot's comment. Direct response to question and helpful edit of question.

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote it I could not comment here yet, so answering was my only alternative to not helping at all.